# Can an underscore be used anywhere in an identifier in C?

Tags: c

I have a simple question: can I use an underscore anywhere in an identifier?

If yes please give an example, and if not please explain why.

Comment: yes it can be used anywhere in an identifier. examples are `#define THIS_IS_A_HASH_DEFINE "junk"` and `int this_is_an_int = 5;`

Comment: Take a look at '5.4 Naming Variables, Functions, and Files' in [GNU Coding Standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html)

Comment: You can even say `int _ = 42;`!

Comment: @devnull There's got to be some IOCCC entry that abuses underscores.

Comment: To the OP: I've made an edit to my answer, to address the _why_ part of your question.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, underscores may appear everywhere in an identifier, `_a`, `_0_` or even `_` are all valid identifiers. But there are a rules which of these you may use in your code and which are reserved for the "implementation" (= compiler and OS).

- identifiers starting with an `_` and a then a capital letter are reserved everywhere, you are not supposed to use them yourself. They can be used freely by the compiler or may be used by future language extensions, e.g this is why the official Boolean type in C is named `_Bool`.
- identifiers starting with an `_` and a then a lower case letter are reserved at file scope, so your are not allowed to name a function or global variable `_toto` or something alike. These could conflict with names of library functions, e.g.
- identifiers with more than one `_` in a row are reserved by C++ for name mangling. If you ever think of writing code in C that is callable from C++ you shouldn't use these.
- identifiers ending with `_t` are reserved by POSIX for types. If you want to avoid future portability issues on new systems, avoid these, too.

There are a lot of other rules for reserved names, I only listed those that I remembered concerning `_`.

Answer (score 5):

**Rules for writing identifier**

1. An identifier can be composed of letters (both uppercase and lowercase letters), digits and underscore '_' only.
2. The first letter of identifier should be either a letter or an underscore. But, it is discouraged to start an identifier name with an underscore though it is legal. It is because, identifier that starts with underscore can conflict with system names. In such cases, compiler will complain about it. Some system names that start with underscore are _fileno, _iob, _wfopen etc.
3. There is no rule for the length of an identifier. However, the first 31 characters of an identifier are discriminated by the compiler. So, the first 31 letters of two identifiers in a program should be different.

Ex:

```
    int identifier;
    int _identifier;
    int new_identifier;
```

Comment: is the identifier `_45` allowed?

Comment: and the `_45a`, is it allowed?

Comment: @MOHAMED Yes, both are.

Comment: Yes they are all valid.

Comment: @MOHAMED: All you needed to do was compare your test names against these three very simple and unambiguous rules.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, underscores can be used as identifiers. Here's an example: [The IOCCC winner of 1988](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest)

```
#define _ -F<00||--F-OO--;
int F=00,OO=00;main(){F_OO();printf("%1.3f\n",4.*-F/OO/OO);}F_OO()
{
            _-_-_-_
       _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
    _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
  _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
 _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
  _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
    _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
        _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
            _-_-_-_
}
```

As to *why* an underscore is allowed anywhere in an identifier, the answer is: the standard describes the syntax of an identifier to be comprised of at least one *nondigit*, followed by zero or more *digit or nondigit* chars
It also defines *nondigits* as being either one of the following chars:

> _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

and digits are:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

So following this rule, `_____` is as valid an identifier as `my_identifier` or `_000000AAFF___`
But be aware that there is such a thing as reserved identifiers, and [these, too, are described in the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1230836).
To answer the *why* question once again: because the standard said so ;-P

Comment: Wait, is this that pi calculator?

Comment: @DennisMeng: Yup, but it's written in K&R, not ANSI C... still, quite nice :)

Answer (score 0):

An Underscore is seen a normal letter/Character

[MSDN Desciption of identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f8y25b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Besides that there are often some Coding guidelines that restrict you in the use of the underscore, e.g. in a constructor the parameters are named _name where the name of the class variable is name.