# Why can't we use of hyphen while declaring structure variable name?

Tags: c, structure

struct birthday{
int day:6;
}b-day;

While declaring **`b-day`** as a structure it shows the following error:

```
error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '-' token|
```

but after removing the hyphen from the variable name it works, why?

Comment: Because you just can't put a hyphen in an identifier name. The syntax forbids it. And thank god it does, I can't imagine the amount of trouble allowing hyphens in names would cause.

Comment: `b-day` is the same as `b - day` which consists of 3 tokens. Some languages do allow `-` in identifiers but C is not one of them. It's a little bit unfortunate because `-` makes it much easier to read than `_`, and it forces the programmer to use proper spacing around operators

Comment: The hyphen is not a valid identifier character.  It has other uses in the C language.  Identifiers in C may contain letters, digits, and underscores, and they must begin with a non-digit.

Comment: Why can't you name your child "Is"?  Because it would be too confusing.  "Is Is a boy or a girl?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boring answer is that the language definition doesn't allow `-` to be part of an identifier (variable name, function name, typedef name, enumeration constant, tag name, etc.).

*Why* that's the case probably boils down to a couple of things:

At the preprocessing stage, your source text is broken up into a sequence of *tokens* - identifiers, punctuators, string literals, and numeric constants.  Whitespace is not significant except that it separates tokens of the same type.  If you write `a=b+c;`, the compiler sees the sequence of tokens *identifier* (`a`), *punctuator* (`=`), *identifier* (`b`), *punctuator* (`+`), *identifier* (`c`), and *punctuator* (`;`).  This is before it does any syntax analysis - it's not looking at the meaning or the structure of that statement, it's just breaking it down into its component parts.

It can do this because the characters `=` and `+` and `;` can *never* be part of an identifier, so it can clearly see where identifiers begin and end<sup>1</sup>.

The tokenizer is "greedy" and will build the longest valid token it can.  In a declaration like

```
int a;
```

you need the whitespace to tell the preprocessor that `int` and `a` are separate tokens, otherwise it will try to mash them together into a single token `inta`.  Similarly, in a statement like `a=b- -c;`, you need that whitespace (or parentheses, `a=b-(-c);`) to signify you're subtracting `-c` from `b`, otherwise the tokenizer will interpret it as `a = b-- c`, which isn't what you want.

So, if a `-` could be part of an identifier, how should `x=a-b+c` be tokenized?  Is `a-b` a single token or three?  How would you write your tokenizer such that it could keep track of that?  Would you require whitespace before and after `-` to signify that it's an operator and not part of a variable?

It's certainly possible to define a language that allows `-` to be both an operator and part of an identifier (see COBOL), but it adds complexity to the tokenizing stage of compiling, and it's just plain *easier* to not allow it.

---

1. Coincidentally, this is why there's no difference between `T *p;` and `T* p;` when declaring pointer variables - the `*` can never be part of an identifier, so whitespace isn't necessary to separate the type from the variable name.  You could write it as `T*p;` or even `T     *      p;` and it will be treated exactly the same.

Comment: the simplest way to allow `-` in identifiers is to just require spaces around binary operators. That's not only good for readability but also follow normal spacing rules in writing

Answer (score 5):

Hyphens are used as subtraction and negation operators, so they cannot be used in variable names. (Whether the variable is for a structure or another type is irrelevant.)

If you had:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int a-b = 3;
printf("%d\n", a-b);
```

then we would have ambiguity about whether to print “-1” for `a` minus `b` or to print “3” for the variable `a-b`.

Answer (score 2):

Because C doesn't allow to use hyphens for identifier names.

Basically you can only use alphabets, digits, and an underscore.
Also using digits as the first character is not allowed.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.4.2 Identifiers:

> Syntax
>
> ```
> identifier:
>     identifier-nondigit
>     identifier identifier-nondigit
>     identifier digit
>
> identifier-nondigit:
>     nondigit
>     universal-character-name
>     other implementation-defined characters
>
> nondigit: one of
>     _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m
>       n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>       A B C D E F G H I J K L M
>       N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> digit: one of
>     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

Comment: I think it's UB to start with underscore

Comment: @klutt according to [Can an underscore be used anywhere in an identifier in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19972251), if you start your identifier with one underscore then the following character can't be an uppercase letter, and if it's a lowercase letter, it should only have file scope. If you abide by that rule, I think it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the symbol `'-'` may not be used in an identifier name. When it is used between a sequence of symbols it is considered by the compiler as the binary or unary minus operator depending on the context.

The error message

> error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or 'attribute' before '-' token|

means that the compiler tries to interpret the declaration at least like

```
    struct birthday{
        int day:6;
    }b; -day;
```

You could declare the structure like

```
    struct birthday{
        int day:6;
    } b_day;
```

that is using the underscore symbol instead of the hyphen symbol.